# Vue.js: Getting data from the api and passing it to a child component (simple example)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I want to make an ajax request using axios package on the parent component and pass the returned array  to a child component so that it can iterate the array and build the layout.  I have the following code.

The parent is this:

```
<script>


     import Box from './Box';
     import axios from 'axios';

   export default {
       name : "messagespainel",
       data: function() {
       return {messsages: []}  //should I use data to pass the ajax returned array to the child
    },
         props: ['messages']  //should I use props to pass the ajax returned array to the child
  }


   mounted : 
   {

        axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=mykey').then(response => {  this.messsages = response.data.Search});


    }

 </script>

   <template>

  <div>
 <box messages="this.messages"></box> My mind bugs at this point. How to refer to messages?
  </div>

  </template>
```

The child is this:

```
  <script>

export default {
name: "box",
props: ['mensagens']

 }

 </script>
  <template>
   <div>
 <div v-for="message in messages" > 
  {{ message}}
  </div>
  </div>

   </template>

   <style>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your parent, there is no need to declare `messages` as a prop, it's a data property you are passing to the child.

```js
    import Box from './Box';
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
       name : "messagespainel",
       data: function() {
         return {messages: []}  
       },
       mounted() {
         axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star&apikey=mykey')
           .then(response => {  this.messages = response.data.Search});
       }
    }
```

In the template, you need to bind the property.

```html
    <box v-bind:messages="messages"></box>
```

or

```html
    <box :messages="messages"></box>
```

The child needs to declare `messages` as a property.

```js
    export default {
      name: "box",
      props: ['messages']
    }
```

Comment: Your answer was very clarifying!.

Comment: In the child, how can I databind the properties in a div? {{ property }} is not working!

Comment: @DiegoAlves In the child, in your loop, it would be `{{message.property}}`, assuming the loop is `v-for="message in messages"`.